# data.table tag rows that have no duplicate values within a column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` like below

```
d_in_small <- data.table( score = c(94.272159,94.751695,106.588274,109.361865,111.017053,113.703024,118.638858,124.007419,125.695266,125.696385,94.272191,94.751649,95.496644,108.902001,113.703027),
                        group = c('a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a'))
```

| id | score | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 94.2721 | a |
| 2 | 94.7516 | a |
| 3 | 106.5882 | a |
| 4 | 109.3618 | a |
| 5 | 111.0170 | a |
| 6 | 113.7030 | a |
| 7 | 118.6388 | a |
| 8 | 124.0074 | a |
| 9 | 125.6952 | a |
| 10 | 125.6963 | a |
| 11 | 94.2721 | a |
| 12 | 94.7516 | a |
| 13 | 95.4966 | a |
| 14 | 108.9020 | a |
| 15 | 113.7030 | a |

I would like to identify which scores occur only once in the dataset. e.g. score in row 1 is in row 11 as well, but score in row 3 is unique.

So, Is there any way to easily identify non-duplicated items in a data.table and add them in a new column to get an output like below?

| id | score | group | tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 94.2721 | a |  |
| 2 | 94.7516 | a |  |
| 3 | 106.5882 | a | outlier |
| 4 | 109.3618 | a | outlier |
| 5 | 111.0170 | a | outlier |
| 6 | 113.7030 | a |  |
| 7 | 118.6388 | a | outlier |
| 8 | 124.0074 | a | outlier |
| 9 | 125.6952 | a | outlier |
| 10 | 125.6963 | a | outlier |
| 11 | 94.2721 | a |  |
| 12 | 94.7516 | a |  |
| 13 | 95.4966 | a | outlier |
| 14 | 108.9020 | a | outlier |
| 15 | 113.7030 | a |  |

The DT snap here is a sample, so they will be grouped by the column `group` when applied in the entire dataset.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are rounding your scores to the 4th decimal. Is that correct

Comment: No values are duplicated, the print out is a just an artifact of the `print.data.table` method. Do you want duplicated after rounding?

Comment: @joe - Yes sorry, didn't clarify. As Rui indicated, duplicates post rounding was what I was after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
d_in_small[,outlier:=if (.N==1) 'outlier',by=score]
```

Note that the example dataset you provide has only outliers because of the last decimals.
You could group by `round(score,decimals)` to get the precision you want to detect outliers.

For example:

```
d_in_small[,outlier:=if (.N==1) 'outlier',by=round(score,4)][]
        score  group outlier
        <num> <char>  <char>
 1:  94.27216      a    <NA>
 2:  94.75169      a outlier
 3: 106.58827      a outlier
 4: 109.36186      a outlier
 5: 111.01705      a outlier
 6: 113.70302      a    <NA>
 7: 118.63886      a outlier
 8: 124.00742      a outlier
 9: 125.69527      a outlier
10: 125.69639      a outlier
11:  94.27216      a    <NA>
12:  94.75165      a outlier
13:  95.49664      a outlier
14: 108.90200      a outlier
15: 113.70303      a    <NA>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. That looks really promising. Only one question, if I wanted to group by the `group` column as well? As it has more than one value in the actual dataset.

Comment: You can group by multiple columns :`by=.(group,round(score,4))`

Comment: Could also just `d_in_small[, outlier := if(.N == 1) 'outlier', by = round(score, 4)]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks! more elegant and a bit faster ;-) updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Mark the duplicates first and then change the `FALSE` value to `outlier` could be one way to handle it

```
d_in_small[, tag := .N > 1, by = score]
d_in_small$tag <- ifelse(d_in_small$tag=='FALSE','outlier','TRUE')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option. I define a rounding function to make the code more readable.

```
f <- function(x) round(x, 4)

d_in_small[, tag := duplicated(f(score)) | duplicated(f(score), fromLast = TRUE)]
d_in_small[, tag := c("outlier", "")[tag + 1L]]
d_in_small
```